# Why doesn't my bot have errors while joining voice? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
if message.content == "%join":
      @client.command()
      async def join(ctx):
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
```

When I type %join it comes up with an error:

```
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 102, in on_message
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'
```

I joined a voice channel but still same error. discord.Client() is renamed client so it client = discord.Client() i did

Comment: I can't see very much of your code, but the fact that you're conditionally defining a bot command *inside* of an if statement after checking the contents of a message indicates to me that there's something very, very wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using @client.command by itself and not inside and if statement.
Here's how you are supposed to do it.

```py
##--Voice Chat Functions--##
@client.command(aliases=['jvc'])
async def joinvc(ctx):
    try:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    except AttributeError:
        await ctx.send("You're Not in a Voice Chat Lmao :joy:"
                       )
    global voice
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice = await channel.connect(timeout=3600)


@client.command(aliases=["lvc"])
async def leavevc(ctx):
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await voice.disconnect()
```

If you are having problems using on_message and commands,
at the end of on_message add `await client.process_commands(message)`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send("Hi!!!!")
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command()
...
...
...
```